# Which design pattern/s should I use when writing a parser?

Tags: .net, parsing, design-patterns, xsd, schema

I am writing XSD parser , which will be used to generate asp.net controls on a form according to the parsed XSD .

The XSD is loaded from some location ( for example from DB) to a XsdSchema object , and then using .NET classes (Schema Object Model) to read the elements of that schema to produce list of controls to be rendered on a form .

Which patterns you think are the best to be used in this scenario ?

(Currently I've created classes to represent different kinds of controls -text , date , list and etc. , and my xsd parser class has a method that returns a list of those classes according to the parsed XSD .

Those "Ui Element" classes were created to somehow not to tie the parser to asp.net layer )

I want to write  the parser in some smart manner according to some design patterns for a simpler changes in the future .

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

TL;DR: Visitor pattern (double dispatch) and Intepreter pattern (recursive function) can be used to translate trees (Composite pattern), in your case, the form elements tree into the UI controls tree. [Here is a smart article on that](http://homepages.cwi.nl/~storm/publications/visitor.pdf).

When parsing, it can be useful to think in terms of trees, rather then lists (your list of controls will most likely have a parent control, so it's in fact a tree). In a nutshell, a tree is a recursive data structure -- a node with scalar id and a list of children, which point to other nodes, whose children also point to other nodes, and so on.

XML can be seen as a tree serialization (graph, in fact, but tree is a common special case) and so can XSD. So, let's say XSD contains a tree of form elements, which needs to be translated to a tree of UI elements.

This can be done by traversing the form tree -- enumerating the nodes in some order, creating a UI control for each node and building up the tree of UI controls.

Two patterns, which come to mind here, are 
Visitor (double dispatch) and Intepreter (recursive function). Here is [some tutorial](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-005-elements-of-software-construction-fall-2011/lecture-notes/MIT6_005F11_lec08.pdf) -- it's in Java, which is translatable to C#.

*Update*: A good description of Visitor pattern as applies to parse trees:

[How to write the Visitor Pattern for Abstract Syntax Tree in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2525677/how-to-write-the-visitor-pattern-for-abstract-syntax-tree-in-python)

> Each node in your AST would need to implement an accept() method (NOT a visit() method). The method takes, as an argument, a visitor object. In the implementation of this accept() method, you call a visit() method of the visitor object (there will be one for each AST node type; in Java, you’ll use parameter overloading, in Python I suppose you can use different visit_*() methods).